# Gathering data frame from wide to long and generating a new column using tidyverse in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data are as follows:

```html
df1<-read.table(text=" A A1 B B1 C C1
12 7 11 4 16 9
12 6 13 8 12 7
14 6 14 2 11 5
13 5 14 3 10 6
11 4 15 6 9 4
10 3 16 7 `8 3
9 2 18 4 `12 12",header=TRUE)
```

I wand to get the following outcome. To save space, I did not generate the rest as I felt it may not  be necessary

```html
Group Time Value
M A 12
N A1 7
M B 11
N B1 4
M C 16
N C1 9
M A 12
N A1 6
M B 13
N B1 8
M C 12
N C1 7
M A 14
N A1 6
M B 14
N B1 2
M C 11
N C1 5
. . .
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

What I have done is:

```html
df2<-gather(df1,Group, Time)
```

A, B, C  are categorised as M and A1, B1 and C1 are catigorised as N. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `Group` be `N` if ends with "1" (and the rest `M`) you can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "Time", values_to = "Value") %>%
  mutate(Group = if_else(endsWith(Time, "1"), "N", "M"))
```

Would recommend using `pivot_longer` instead of `gather` with newest `tidyr` going forward, as its replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an additional column using `if_else`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
group1 <- names(df1)[grepl(".+1$", names(df1))]
df <- tidyr::gather(df1, Time, Value) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Group = if_else(Time %in% group1, "N", "M"))
```

After that, you can arrange your rows and columns in the way you like.

**Output**

```
Time Value Group
1     A    12     M
2     A    12     M
3     A    14     M
4     A    13     M
5     A    11     M
6     A    10     M
7     A     9     M
8    A1     7     N
9    A1     6     N
10   A1     6     N
11   A1     5     N
12   A1     4     N
13   A1     3     N
14   A1     2     N
15    B    11     M
...
```

Comment: Then you have to clarify your question to make it clear what you want to achieve. For example, how to assign variables to group. What is the role of `1` in variable names?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df1<-read.table(text=" A    A1  B   B1  C   C1
12  7   11  4   16  9
12  6   13  8   12  7
14  6   14  2   11  5
13  5   14  3   10  6
11  4   15  6   9   4
10  3   16  7   8   3
9   2   18  4   12  12",header=TRUE)

df2 = gather(df1)

df2$Group = ifelse(grepl('\\d', x = df2$key), 'N', 'M')
```

Change the column names accordingly.

Result:

```
> df2
   key value Group
1    A    12     M
2    A    12     M
3    A    14     M
4    A    13     M
5    A    11     M
6    A    10     M
7    A     9     M
8   A1     7     N
9   A1     6     N
10  A1     6     N
11  A1     5     N
12  A1     4     N
13  A1     3     N
...
```

Comment: The problem is A, A1, B, B1 ... are hypothetical and if I have another column names, these codes do not work.

Comment: Why the downvote? It does the same as the other answers (that were copied from this)

Comment: @R.Schifini making claims that all the answers were copied from yours is not the smartest thing, especially if you look at the time stamps